# plotting points on kernel density function unsuccessful in R

Tags: r, class, kernel-density, probability-density, density-plot

I'm trying to get some `points` on my density plot for the `seq(-3, 3)` [i.e., 7 numbers]. I get the 7 corresponding density values but when I try to execute `points`, I get:

`Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

As really there is no length difference, I assume there is `class()` difference problem between x, and y for `points()`.
I appreciate a solution?

**Here is the R code:**

```
positions = rnorm(1e4)

DENS = density(positions, adjust = 2, n = 1e4)

x.DENS = DENS$x
y.DENS = DENS$y

plot( DENS, col = "red", lwd = 3, xlab = "Positions",
  ylab = "Density", xlim = c(-6, 6), main = 
  NA, bty = 'n', zero.line = F)

x.DENS.2 = seq(-3, 3)
y.DENS.2 = approx(x.DENS, y.DENS, xout = x.DENS.2 ) ## get the x.DENS.2 density values

points(x.DENS.2, y.DENS.2) ## Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `y.DENS.2`-object is actually a list with x and y components:

```
str(y.DENS.2 )
List of 2
 $ x: int [1:7] -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3
 $ y: num [1:7] 0.00514 0.0642 0.23952 0.37896 0.24057 ...
```

... so you can just use

```
points(y.DENS.2, col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last line is incorrect. Please change it to

> points(x.DENS.2, y.DENS.2$y)

Here is the full codes. It works on my side. So, when you plot the results, it will be very helpful to check the dimension of your inputs to make sure that they matched.

```
positions = rnorm(1e4)

DENS = density(positions, adjust = 2, n = 1e4)

x.DENS = DENS$x
y.DENS = DENS$y

plot( DENS, col = "red", lwd = 3, xlab = "Positions",
      ylab = "Density", xlim = c(-6, 6), main = 
        NA, bty = 'n', zero.line = F)

x.DENS.2 = seq(-3, 3)
y.DENS.2 = approx(x.DENS, y.DENS, xout = x.DENS.2 ) ## get the x.DENS.2 density values

points(x.DENS.2, y.DENS.2$y)
```